# How were the truth tables defined

Tags: logic

How were the truth tables defined?

I mean, why $1 \land 1=1$ instead of $1 \land 1=0$?

What was this based on?

Comment: Suppose Alex is a cat and that Alex is a cat. Is Alex not a cat?

Comment: It would help us explain if you were to have a firmer grasp on English grammar.  Suffice to say, the meaning and use of logical conjunction ($\wedge$) is included as an axiom.  This is done to mimic the use and usefulness of the word `and` or translations of the word in english or in other languages.

Comment: You might find a more satisfying explanation on the [wikipedia page for logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction).

Comment: The truth tables has been defined in order to reflect the natural language way of using the connectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of 1 as meaning "true", 0 as meaning "false", and ^ as meaning "and". So if you combine two true statements by joining them with an "and", the resulting statement is true.

Comment: but why 1^1=1? who defined that? and what is the justification to do that?

Comment: @Aben Well, if A is true and B is true, what do you think "A and B" is? Do you think "A and B" can be *false* if A is true and B is true?

Comment: I don't know, I mean the book say 1^1=1, but, what is the justification about this statement?

Comment: I don't know who originally made that definition, but the reason it is interesting and useful to define ^ in this way is because it corresponds to what happens when you combine two true statements using "and".

Comment: @Aben This **is** the justification. Do you agree with me that if $A$ is true and $B$ is true, then "$A$ and $B$" is true? If not, why not?

Comment: @ Noah Schweber , Yes I am agree with you. If A is true and B is true, the result A ^ B is true, because all is true. Now If A=0 and B=1, A^B=0, why is that result?

Comment: @Aben It's defined in this way because it turns out to be useful. You can define $1 \land 1=0$ yourself. If it turns out to be even more useful, people will follow you.

Comment: @Aben $0 \land 1=0$ because not all is true

Comment: @Aben Suppose A is false and B is true. Is "A and B" true or false? Think about what the symbols **mean**, not just about the symbols themselves.